# Codeigniter 4 Complex UNION queries

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, union

I am new to Codeigniter 4 and trying to write SELECT UNION SQL Statements. According to the user guide in codeigniter 4, there is a second parameter in select() method that allows to write custom SQL Statements by setting it to false. Unfortunately it is not working. Can someone help please? Is there any alternate solution?

```
$query = "SELECT acnt_id, acnt_opbal as sum_amount 
                        FROM accounts 
                            WHERE acnt_id = '" . $acnt_id . "' 
                    UNION 
                    SELECT txn_acnt_id_dr as acnt_id, SUM(txn_amount_dr) as sum_amount 
                        FROM transactions 
                            WHERE txn_acnt_id_dr = '" . $acnt_id . "' 
                                AND txn_date < '" . $fdate . "'
                            GROUP BY txn_acnt_id_dr 
                    UNION 
                    SELECT txn_acnt_id_cr as acnt_id, -SUM(txn_amount_cr) as sum_amount 
                        FROM transactions 
                            WHERE txn_acnt_id_cr = '" . $acnt_id . "' 
                                AND txn_date < '" . $fdate . "'
                            GROUP BY txn_acnt_id_cr";
$result = $this->builder()->select($query, false)->get()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [CodeIgniter 4 Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#get) ->getResult() should be used after building the query in order to produce your query

```
<?php 
$builder = $db->table('mytable'); 
$query   = $builder->get();  // Produces: SELECT * FROM mytable

foreach ($query->getResult() as $row) {
    echo $row->title;
}
```

Addapting this to your code you'll get:

```
<?php 
$builder = $this->builder()->select($query, false); 
$query   = $builder->get();
$result  = $query->getResult();
```

Or make it all 1 line you can use [Covariance and Contravariance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php#language.oop5.variance):

```
$result = ($this->builder()->select($query, false)->get())->getResult();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But getResult() was already used. Problem was with the kind of query statement. The UNION of SELECT was not working. I wanted to know if there is any other way of achieving a UNION?